# Linux - Управление нагрузками на ядро CPU

Tags: linux, manjaro

Можно ли в *Manjaro* сделать так, чтобы нагрузка концентрировалась на одно ядро только для определенной программы?

Comment: Какую задачу решаете? перегреть процессор локально?

Comment: Увеличить производительность

Comment: Это не увеличит производительность.  Даже скорее всего понизит. Другие ядра будут простаивать.

Comment: Перераспределние нагрузки не увеличит производительность процессора?

Comment: @IliaIvanov  нагрузка всей ОС или же одной программе выделить целое ядро?

Comment: Выделить под программу

Answer (score 0):

[Taskset](https://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset) позволяет вам «привязывать» процесс к определённому процессору. 
Стоит заметить:

> Обратите внимание, что Taskset пытается сохранить процессы на одном и том же процессоре, насколько это возможно по соображениям производительности.

Приоритет CPU представлен как битовая маска, причем бит младшего разряда соответствует первому логическому процессору и бит наивысшего порядка, соответствующий последнему логическому процессору.

Представим, что вы хотите настроить Google Chrome так, чтобы он работал только на одном CPU. Делается это командой:

```
taskset 0x00000001 google-chrome
taskset -c 0 google-chrome --option
```

Установить для уже запущенного процесса

```
taskset -c -p PID
```

Если вы хотите узнать, на каких процессорах выполняется тот или иной процесс, вы можете воспользоваться командой:

```
taskset -p XXXX
```

Подробнее о taskset  [тут](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=taskset&category=1&russian=2) и [тут](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_MRG/1.3/html/Realtime_Reference_Guide/chap-Realtime_Reference_Guide-Affinity.html)

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, но жаль, что это увеличит производительность.